# class inheritance and constructor

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Im trying to get the results as follows

```
let hobbes = new Employee("Hobbes", 1000000, "Founder", null);
console.log(hobbes.bonus(0.05)); // 50000

let calvin = new Manager("Calvin", 130000, "Director", "Hobbes");
console.log(calvin.bonus(0.05)); // 6500

let susie = new Manager("Susie", 100000, "TA Manager", "Calvin");
console.log(susie.bonus(0.05)); // 14000

let lily = new Employee("Lily", 90000, "TA", "Susie");
console.log(lily.bonus(0.05)); // 4500

let clifford = new Employee("Clifford", 90000, "TA", "Susie");
console.log(clifford.bonus(0.05)); // 4500
```

But I am confused on getting the salaries from the Managers employess. From theses classes. The instructions were. *You can extract the logic of calculating the total salary of all a manager's employees into a totalSubsalary() method.
To do this, you can iterate through each of a manager's employees, checking if the employee is an instance of a Manager or not, and calculate the totalSubsalary.*

```
class Employee {
  constructor(name, salary, title, bosss) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.bosss = bosss;
  }
  bonus(multiplier) {
    return this.salary * multiplier;
  }
}


class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(name, salary, title, employees) {
    super(name, salary, title);
    this.employees = employees;
  }
  bonus(multiplier) {
    return this.salary * multiplier;
  }
  totalSubSalary() {
    for (let key in this.employees) {
      const element = this.employees;
      console.log(this.name instanceof Manager);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create all the employees first. Then create the managers and pass an array of employees to the manager constructor.

```js
class Employee {
  constructor(name, salary, title) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.bosss = null; // The manager will assign this
  }
  bonus(multiplier) {
    return this.salary * multiplier;
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(name, salary, title, employees) {
    super(name, salary, title);
    // employees should be an array of Employee objects
    this.employees = employees;
    // Assign each employees manager to me
    this.employees.forEach((e) => {
      e.bosss = this;
    });
  }

  // No need to override bonus() function

  totalSubSalary() {
    return this.employees.reduce((a, b) => {return a + b.salary;}, 0);
  }
}

// Create the employees
let hobbes = new Employee("Hobbes", 1000000, "Founder");
console.log(hobbes.bonus(0.05)); // 50000

let lily = new Employee("Lily", 90000, "TA");
console.log(lily.bonus(0.05)); // 4500

let clifford = new Employee("Clifford", 90000, "TA");
console.log(clifford.bonus(0.05)); // 4500

// Create the managers
let calvin = new Manager("Calvin", 130000, "Director", [hobbes]);
console.log(calvin.bonus(0.05)); // 6500

let susie = new Manager("Susie", 100000, "TA Manager", [lily, clifford]);
console.log(susie.bonus(0.05)); // 5000

console.log(susie.totalSubSalary());
```